# Effeciently Searching a Hash Table without using the Key

Tags: c++, search, hashtable

I have a Hash Table with a list of songs. Each song-node is being inserted to the table by translating the title of the song into it's ascii characters and using this number [% table size] as the key. There is also an "artist" field in each song-node. If I wanted to display every song by a particular artist, could I do so without searching every single node in the entire table? I included my insertion and hashing methods below. On a side note, what is an appropriate name for a hash function?

Header file:

```
struct song {
    string title;
    string artist;
    song* next;
};

class hash {
public:
    hash();
    int Hash_Key(string key); // For determining the hash key for a string
    // Do I need to use multiple hash functions or multiple strings?
    int Add_Item(string title, string artist); // for adding song to hash table
private:
    static const int tableSize = 7;
    song* HashTable[tableSize];
};
```

Implementation:

```
int hash::Add_Item(string title, string artist) {
    int index = Hash_Key(name);
    if(HashTable[index]->title == "empty") { // if first item at this index
        HashTable[i]->title = title;
        HashTable[i]->artist = artist;
    }
    else { // if not the first item at this index
        song* temp = HashTable[index];
        song* n = new song;
        n->title = title;
        n->artist = artist;
        n->next = NULL;
        while(temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = n;
    }


    return 0; // temporary
};

int hash::Hash_Key(string key) {
    int hash = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        hash = hash + (int)key[i];
    }

    index = hash % tableSize; // remainder of the sum of ascii values of key
                              // divided by tableSize
    return index;
}
```

Comment: "Searching a Hash Table without using the Key" - Best you can do is O(N)

Comment: That's not a very good hash function. See http://research.cs.vt.edu/AVresearch/hashing/strings.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to create a new map of "artist -> song*" and keep both maps up-to-date as you add/remove items.

Comment: So like a second hash table, but using the artist as the key?